# How to create card with image and content by using grid layout method css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am developing a website in html and css and I want to have a card that contains an image, content and images to social network links.

[image]

So I want to align the text and images with distances like in the image below and all this using the css grids and the card.

```css
/* body rules included when showing the example as a live example */

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 1.2em / 1.5 Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px darkgray solid;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 200px 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card .content {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <article class="card">

    <img src="https://photos2.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP994/mango-clip-art__k16208308.jpg" alt="Hot air balloons">
    <div class="content1 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 0. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content2 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 1 . </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content3 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 2. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content4 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 3. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content4 content">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    </div>

  </article>
</div>
```

How can I do it ? Do you have any ideas to improve my code and get the expected result in my layout

Comment: where is the issue by just adding a margin-bottom to every element?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a gap between all elemnts of 16px you can just add:
`.card { grid-row-gap: 16px; }`

This however will also add a 16px gap between the picture and the following element. Since you want to make it only 8px high you add a negative margin to the 2nd element:
`.card > nth-child(2) { margin-top: -8px; }`

```css
/* body rules included when showing the example as a live example */

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 1.2em / 1.5 Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px darkgray solid;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 200px 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card .content {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
}


/* added CSS */
.card {
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
}

.card > :nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: -8px;
}

/* for visualisation */
.card > * {
  display: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <article class="card">

    <img src="https://photos2.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP994/mango-clip-art__k16208308.jpg" alt="Hot air balloons">
    <div class="content1 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 0. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content2 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 1 . </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content3 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 2. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content4 content">
      <p> The idea of reaching the North Pole 3. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content4 content">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    </div>

  </article>
</div>
```